# Share variable from producer process to all consumer processes

Tags: python, multithreading, events, multiprocessing

Application represents stream splitter - producer process is receiving data stream and multiple consumer processes (client connections) send (pass) received data to connected client.

I've found this [sample code](http://www.dabeaz.com/usenix2009/concurrent/cond.py) for `Condition Variable` (it's using `multithreading` but it should work for `multiprocessing` also) and refactored it so it doesn't pop item in consumer process. That's how I expected that other consumer process will be able to reuse it and resend same data to connected clients. Once all consumer processes finish sending I'd remove `item[0]` from buffer array. But this is not working since processes are not executing in predictable order.

```
1. Receive new data - Producer process
2. Send received data - Consumer process [1]
3. Send received data - Consumer process [2]
...
n. Send received data - Consumer process [n]
Loop everything.
```

Usually happens that producer process removes `item[0]` before all Consumer processes get to retrieve `item[0]` and send it.

I guess one possible solution would be to use separate `Queue()` for each consumer process and in producer process to populate those separate queues.

Is it possible to use `Event()` to notify consumer process that new data arrived and then pass that data independently from other consumer processes without queue?

If using queue is best solution is it possible to use only one queue and keep new data until all consumer processes finish sending it?

I'm open to any suggestions since I'm not sure what's is the best way to do this.

```
import threading
import time

# A list of items that are being produced.  Note: it is actually
# more efficient to use a collections.deque() object for this.

items = []

# A condition variable for items
items_cv = threading.Condition()

# A producer thread
def producer():
    print "I'm the producer"
    for i in range(30):
        with items_cv:          # Always must acquire the lock first
            items.append(i)     # Add an item to the list
            items_cv.notify()   # Send a notification signal
        time.sleep(1)
        items.pop(0)            # Pop item remove it from the "buffer"


# A consumer thread
def consumer():
    print "I'm a consumer", threading.currentThread().name
    while True:
        with items_cv:           # Must always acquire the lock
            while not items:     # Check if there are any items
                items_cv.wait()  # If not, we have to sleep
            # x = items.pop(0)     # Pop an item off
            x = items[0]
        print threading.currentThread().name,"got", x
        time.sleep(5)


# Launch a bunch of consumers
cons = [threading.Thread(target=consumer)
        for i in range(10)]

for c in cons:
    c.setDaemon(True)
    c.start()

# Run the producer
producer()
```

Comment: Just a quick observation. If i understand you correctly, you want all consumers to finish on item 0 before any of them start with item 1, which would make any consumer able to block all the others. That is in my experience something one normally wants to avoid. A separate queue per consumer would avoid that problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "Once all consumer processes finish sending I'd remove item[0] from buffer array". The consumer does not seem to send anything; it's simply printing an number/item

Comment: @ViktorFougstedt You're right...I want to force all consumers to finish sending `item[0]` before any of them start sending `item[1]`. In ideal case I will never have to use `item[1]` since after all consumers finish with `item[0]` I would simply remove it and add new (just received) value to item array.

@Pandrei It's just an example from the given link. Instead of that in Consumer process I have client socked through which I send `item[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to solve this problem is to have `Queue` per each client. In my acceptor (listener) function I have this peace of code which creates buffer/queue for each incoming connection.

```
        buffer = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.client_buffers.append(buffer)
        process = multiprocessing.Process(name=procces_name,
                                          target=self.stream_handler,
                                          args(conn, address, buffer))
        process.daemon = True
        process.start()
```

In the main (producer) thread each queue is populated as soon as new data arrives.

```
while True:
    data = sock.recv(2048)
    if not data: break
    for buffer in self.client_buffers:
        buffer.put(data)
```

And each consumer process sends data independently

```
if not buffer.empty():
   connection.sendall(buffer.get())
```